# Windows Task Scheduler, python script, code 2147942401

Tags: python, sqlite, task, scheduler, exit

Having some odd trouble scheduling a task for a python script. Specifically this script and the problem is intermittent, which made me hesitant to pose the question because I'm very confused. I have other scheduled scripts that run fine. This one is the only one modifying a SQLite database though.

I call the script daily, I've done this several ways with the same result. I finally settled on Action "start a program", Program/script: "python" (it is in my path, but i've also directly called py.exe and pyw.exe, with the same result). Add arguments: "scriptname.py". Start in "location of script and database file" which the account I'm using in the scheduler has full read/write/execute access to. And I've instructed this to work whether or not the user is logged in.

I use this same operation for several other scripts and they are fine, this one just doesn't work sometimes. It always runs, but every few days it exits with code 2147942401 instead of 0. On these days the database is not updated, so I suppose it had trouble writing? I'm not sure. It seems this error code in windows is associated with invalid function, but I can manually run the script and everything is fine. And half the days (not exactly half, seemingly randomly), it doesn't work. This never happened until about 3 weeks ago. Nothing changed that I'm aware of, everything has been running fine for months and then bam, exit code 2147942401. It did it several days in a row, and then no problems for a few days. Never a problem running task (or script) manually. It is set to run with highest privileges.

Anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: That error code suggests to me that your Python script is exiting with error code 1.  Does your Python script write any log messages, error messages etc. to a log anywhere?  If not, that would be the next thing to look at doing.

Comment: I can add some logging to it. It runs fine manually. So there are no errors in the script, except that perhaps writing to the database is occasionally impossible? I'll modify the script to write its own log and see if it is failing to finish. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Turns out it was my script breaking. This is the error code (oddly enough there's not much documentation) you get when your python program ends with code -1 (exits without finishing properly or has some unhandled exception). It was intermittent because I was checking a web page and sometimes that web server just didn't respond for any number of reason. Leaving this here for posterity. If you get this error code in task scheduler, write some logging and error handling into your script because it may be a weird problem you didn't think of.

Comment: Glad to hear you got to the bottom of this.

Comment: This is not a Python error. It is a Windows Task Scheduler code.

Comment: I didn't say it was a python error. Although, python caused it. Python did not handle the error so I got this error in Task Scheduler. I was just trying to figure out why when the script ran on its own just fine. I needed better error handling in Python.